# Javascript to disable or enable radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to do something a bit more complicated than this, but I broke it down and threw it in `JSFIDDLE` and I still can't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XYb4/)

HTML:

```
<label for="service-type">Value</label>
<select id="service-type" onChange="hamburger()">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<label for="receiptNo">No</label>
<input type="radio" name="receipt" id="receiptNo">
<label for="receiptYes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="receipt" id="receiptYes">
```

Javascript:

```
var e = document.getElementById("service-type");
var ServiceUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

function hamburger() {
   if (ServiceUser.value === "2") {
      document.getElementById("receiptNo").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("receiptYes").checked = true; 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send the details of function caller like this

```
<select id="service-type" onchange="hamburger(this)">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="radio" name="receipt" id="receiptNo">
<input type="radio" name="receipt" id="receiptYes">
```

Finish it up with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hamburger(sender) { // sender here has all details of dropdown
        if (sender.value === "2") {
            document.getElementById("receiptNo").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("receiptYes").checked = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And there it is! I knew I was forgetting something.  It's been too long since I've written functions.